# How Can I Find Inorder Successor Or Predecessor In A Set In C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, set

A Set in C++ STL is implemented Using Red Black/ AVL Tree Or Any Other Self Balancing tree. So, How can i find inorder successor or inorder predecessor in it??

Comment: Increment or decrement the iterator, `++` or `--`? Because that's what that does?

Comment: *A Set in C++ STL is implemented Using Red Black Self Balancing tree* -- There is no guarantee it is implemented this way.   There is no official "tree" STL container.

Comment: This would be dependent on the implementation. So there is no answer.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.  If so, I bet that you are supposed to implement the tree yourself, and thus implement the successor and predecessor functions.  The answer you gave is nothing more than what `std::next` provides, tree or no tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set<int> s;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s.insert(i);
}

// returns an iterator pointing to x
auto p = s.insert(x);

// inorder successor can be found with incrementing iterator
// if it doesn't exists iterator to end to will be returned

if (++p.first != s.end()) {
    cout << *p.first  << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is all handled by [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).